# How can we use YUI 2.9 and YUI 3.3 on same html?

Tags: javascript, yui

In CMS I am using there is default javascript library YUI 3.3 and there is one component custom gallery using yui 2.9.

I want to include this component in this CMS, what is best possible way to make work both default yui and also custom yui?

Comment: @Warezdesign. It is already documented at YUI => http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/yui/yui-compat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could look at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/yui/yui-compat.html for an example